# What does the Longsword's rage attack do?

Tags: let-it-die

Normally rage attacks (triangle button + either R2 or L2) will make you perform a very strong attack at the expense of your rage gauge. However, when using the Longsword, it appears that I enter a countering stance, but I've never countered an attack while doing it, nor have I ever dealt damage with it. What is the Longsword's rage attack supposed to do? I feel like I'm missing something crucial, since it's an otherwise amazing weapon.

Answer (score 1):

It's a parry. Melee attacks iirc.

Comment: I've been hit while doing it, though. Is there some sort of window I'm missing?